# How to send an image using Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I am using puppeteer, and I want to send a screenshot of the webpage if there is an error. The screenshot is taken correctly, but I cannot send the screenshot. I keep getting [object Object] in the channel instead of the image.

```js
 let message = new Discord.MessageAttachment(await page.screenshot({
        quality:10,
        type:'jpeg'
    }),"ERRORIMAGE.png")
    mainChannel.send({files:[message]});
```

I have also tried .send(message), .send('error image',message), and  .send({attachments:[message]}).
I also tried saving the image as a file then giving the path but that also just gave [object Object].

Comment: what is eror coming on sending screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is sending it through a Discord.messageEmbed using the setImage method on it .

```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setImage('insert the url of the image here') 
mainChannel.send(embed)
```

If it is an image you will be using frequently you might need to host it somewhere for better response times.
[here is a link for a guide on Discord.MessageEmbed](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-an-embed-object)
it also includes stuff related to Discord.MessageAttachments which you can check out

Comment: this would work but its not what the OP is asking for

Comment: The image is a buffer in memory and isnt hosted anywhere. I also dont want to write to disk. the image is a screenshot of a website, so its gonna be different every time so I cant   host it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for a slightly different syntax

```js
//I will not include the screenshot code, since you said that was working fine, and I will therefore assume you do not need help with that

let message = new Discord.MessageAttachment(await page.screenshot({quality:10,type:'jpeg'}),"ERRORIMAGE.png");

message.channel.send('Message that goes above image - can be removed for no message', {
   files: [message.path] //can attach multiple files, simply add more commma delimited filepaths
});
```

This should work - make sure to add the **filepath** of the image, not just its name

**Edit:** the `[object, Object]` error occurs when you try to use an object without specifying what part you are using. This means that most likely you need to do `message.path` or something similar, since `message` is an object.

Comment: the image is a buffer in memory tho. I would rather not write the image to disk every time the screenshot is taken

Comment: okay, ill update my code, give me a second - actually, your code should work, if the path is the actual message element. I would advise doing `message.path` or something, but your code should be working.